# How can i get Azure metrics using the az command in Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

How can i get the Azure metrics , failed requests , app performance, CPU usage and Memory usage ?

There is the az monitor metrics list --resource
[--aggregation {Average, Count, Maximum, Minimum, None, Total}]
[--dimension]
[--end-time]
[--filter]
[--interval]
[--metadata]
[--metrics]
[--namespace]
[--offset]
[--orderby]
[--resource-group]
[--resource-namespace]
[--resource-parent]
[--resource-type]
[--start-t

I have tried to use t as follows

```
     az monitor metrics list --resource "AppServiceName"
```

but get and error:

```
az : usage error: --resource ID | --resource NAME --resource-group NAME --resource-type 
TYPE [--resource-parent PARENT] [--resource-namespace NAMESPACE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Old now - but the resource ID required takes a few forms for example

/subscriptions/b6ff2c43-9c91-4c25-bf05-62fdea862e7b/resourceGroups/My-RSG/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/mywhatever.

This is found in the properties seciton of the portal for example.

[image: Properties->Resource ID]

you can then run in azure cli

`az monitor metrics list --resource /subscriptions/b6ff2c43-9c91-4c25-bf05-62fdea862e7b/resourceGroups/My-RSG/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/mywhatever.`