# How can i get metrics for an Azure database using powershell?

Tags: powershell

How can i use az.monitor command to get an Azure database metrics or is there a different command ?

At the moment i use

```
            $db_metric_storage = $db_resource | Get-AzMetric -MetricName 'storage'
            $db_UsedSpace = $db_metric_storage.Data.Maximum | Select-Object -Last 1
            $db_UsedSpace = [math]::Round($db_UsedSpace / 1GB, 5)

            # Database used space percentage
            $db_metric_storage_percent = $db_resource | Get-AzMetric -MetricName    'storage_percent'
            $db_UsedSpacePercentage = $db_metric_storage_percent.Data.Maximum | Select-Object -Last 1

     I get $db_resource by using 

     $db_resource = az resource list --name $db.name
```

I dont want to use the Get-AzMetric call but just use the az cmds . Is there a way i can do this using powershell az cmds ?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71949681/how-can-i-get-azure-metrics-using-the-az-command-in-powershell

Comment: The "mywhatever" what are those values and what can they take ? Is there a list of reserved words to use ?

Comment: Also do you need to take metrics of the App Service Plan ? I thought it would be of the sqlserver ?

Comment: tried a few doesnt seem to return the value ?